# How to parse a read stream in hapi?

Tags: node.js, stream, hapi.js

How can I parse and validate a readable stream payload sent by http from a client within a hapi server handler?  Handler code looks like this at present

```
{
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        request.payload.pipe(process.stdout);
        return reply('Success');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short explanation: You don't need to parse it, that's **automatic** by default. Just validate the same way you would with a normal request.

By default, hapi will buffer up the readable stream coming from a chunked-encoding transfer into memory and then attempt to **parse it for you** depending on the request `Content-type` header. The handler will be run **only once the stream has ended**. This is because of the default options of the `payload` [config](http://hapijs.com/api#route-options) setting.

```
server.route({
    config: {
        payload: {
            output: 'data',   // These are default options
            parse: true       // These are default options
        }
    }
    method: 'POST',
    path: '/',
    handler: function (request, reply) {

        console.log(request.payload); // This is an Object
        return reply('Success');
    }
});
```

So if the client sends a JSON request, `request.payload` will be a JavaScript object, not a stream. You can validate it just as a normal object using [Joi](http://hapijs.com/tutorials/validation).

Comment: When posting the stream to this endpoint with the options in config like you have stated I am getting a 400 response with a message "Invalid request payload JSON format".  Maybe my question was not clear but I want to be able to handle an incoming readable stream from client side and validate it on server before processing request in handler.

Comment: Are you sending a valid JSON body?

Comment: Nope the stream was multiple separate objects not in an array and not comma separated so was not a valid JSON body.  However I still can't parse an incoming stream into an object for further validation.  I have tried your suggestions however when changing config.payload.output to data it expects a json object and not a stream which is what I am trying to parse.

Comment: You can't parse a stream per se. You can only parse chunks that come off the stream or the entire buffered content. The default settings are failing you because hapi is trying to parse the entire buffered content, which isn't in a valid format. Therefore you need to set `parse` to `false` and `output` to `stream` and request.payload will be an instance of a readable stream. You can then buffer/parse/validate it manually however you wish.

Comment: I will accept your answer as you have explained things that I didn't understand and the docs where not clear in describing.   My understanding now is I will have to write a method that reads each chunk to rebuild json array before it can be validated and stored in a database.